# How delete remaining photos AFTER reset from Photo Stream on icloud and on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photo-stream, camera, photos.app

After having reset Photo Stream on icloud.com and turned off Photo Stream in the pref. on my iPhone, deleting all photos, I still got a total of 423MB worth of images on my iPhone.

According to the usage data I've got:
0 bytes - Camera roll,
42,3MB - Photo library,
381MB - Photo Stream.

I have deleted all photos in the camera app. No photos, videos, no nothing. Likewise, opening the Photos app, no images are available. Still I am supposed to have those 423MB of photos somewhere. I have rebooted the phone with no improvement.

Where are the photos and how do I kill them?! They are haunting me!